# Why is the BiPredicate.test Method not visible in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
return VAL_MAP.getOrDefault(push.type, listOf { _: Push, _: SystemState -> false}.stream().allMatch ( { predicate -> predicate.test(push, systemState)}))
```

I have a line where Push is the push notification parameter, and systemstate is the system settings, you need to filter them out. In Java, the code works fine. For some reason, kotlin swears at the lack of the predicate test method, what could be the problem and how to fix it? And is it possible to write equivalent code, but not to use BiPredicate?

Comment: What is the type of `VAL_MAP`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not specifying that you want to create an object implementing BiPredicate interface. You're creating Kotlin functional object using lambda syntax. So it has type `(Push, SystemState) -> Boolean` instead of type `BiPredicate`. It's easy to fix: just write `BiPredicate{ ... }` instead of `{ ... }`.

So your fixed code would look like

```
return VAL_MAP.getOrDefault(push.type, listOf(BiPredicate { t: Push, u: SystemState -> false }).stream().allMatch({ predicate -> predicate.test(push, systemState) }))
```

Another alternative is just to call functional object as a function instead of using Java interface:

```
return VAL_MAP.getOrDefault(push.type, listOf { t: Push, u: SystemState -> false }.stream().allMatch({ predicate -> predicate(push, systemState) }))
```

Here's full example with type placeholders to demonstrate that it returns Boolean value:

```
package test

import java.util.function.BiPredicate

class PushType
class Push {
    val type = PushType()
}

class SystemState

val VAL_MAP = hashMapOf<PushType, Boolean>()

fun f1(push: Push, systemState: SystemState): Boolean {
    return VAL_MAP.getOrDefault(push.type, listOf(BiPredicate { t: Push, u: SystemState -> false }).stream().allMatch({ predicate -> predicate.test(push, systemState) }))
}

fun f2(push: Push, systemState: SystemState): Boolean {
    return VAL_MAP.getOrDefault(push.type, listOf { t: Push, u: SystemState -> false }.stream().allMatch({ predicate -> predicate(push, systemState) }))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but your examples return the type any when the boolean type is needed. We need the boolean type because it is used in 
val validPushes: MutableList <Push> = IntStream.range (0, pushQuantity) .mapToObj ({inx -> readPush ()}). Filter ({push -> processor.validatePush (push, state )}). collect (Collectors.toList ());

Comment: Actually they return Boolean value. I added full example to demonstrate that.